# Cycle through xml to add missing tag

Tags: xml, vb.net, tags

I'm working on an XML file that has opening tags followed by some child tags with inner text. When the opening tag appears again, it does so with no closing tag for the previous one. So for example, the file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<invoice>
    <id>999</id>
    <newRa elem="0">
        <createD>20150519</createD>
        <modD>12345</modD>
    </newRa>
    <total>123.99</total>
<invoice>
```

I want to create a vb sub that uses xPath to add an "/invoice" tag on every occurence of "invoice".

Should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<invoice>
    <id>999</id>
    <newRa elem="0">
        <createD>20150519</createD>
        <modD>12345</modD>
    </newRa>
    <total>123.99</total>
</invoice>
<invoice>
...
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file is small enough to be opened in its entirety, you can use:

```
Dim st As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("C:\temp\test.xml")
st = st.Replace("</total>", "</total>" & vbCrLf & "</invoice>")
My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("c:\temp\test.xml", st, False)
```

If the file is large, create a streamreader that reads each line and use a line similar to the `st = st.Replace...` line above to to add the additional tag in the right place, and append each line to a new file.

Comment: I'm working with a 200MB xml file, so it's throwing the system.outofmemory exception. Any workaround for this?

Comment: I don't have a 200 MB xml file to test with so I can't be sure, but you probably can use a streamreader to read each line and append it to a new file. When the line content equals "</total>", you'll need to append `"</total>" & vbCrLf & </invoice>"`https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db5x7c0d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Yea, I actually started using streamreader but using your piece where it replaces the closing tag with the same tag, adds a line, and adds the invoice close tag. Will let you know, thanks!